# jQuery .val() concatenation rather than addition

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#negativecustomnicotinevgInput, 
#positivecustomnicotinevgInput").click(function(){
  if($(this).attr("id") == "negativecustomnicotinevgInput"){
      $("#customnicotinepgInput").val($("#customnicotinepgInput").val()+5);
  }
  else if($(this).attr("id") == "positivecustomnicotinevgInput"){
    $("#customnicotinepgInput").val($("#customnicotinepgInput").val()-5);
  }
});
```

When I click on the button `positivecustomnicotinevgInput` this reduces the value by 5. However, when clicking on `negativecustomnicotinevgInput` this actually concatenates the number 5 rather than adding it to the value.

For example, the value 50 becomes 505 then 5055 rather than the expected 55 and 60 by adding 5.

Comment: if they are integers, you should parse them first: `parseInt($("#customnicotinepgInput").val())` otherwise it will treat the value as text (and concatenate the number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `+` is used for string concatenation too. When using `-`, JS does a conversion from the string of an input (containing a number) to a number. When using `+`, js doesn't necessary does this conversion.

To fix that behaviour, you can force a conversion, using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) this in example :

```
$("#customnicotinepgInput").val(parseInt($("#customnicotinepgInput").val(), 10) + 5);
//                              ^-------^-------------------------------------^-------Notice this
```

Comment: Thats fixed the problem! I totally forgot that input boxes could be interpreted as strings. As soon as I gain enough rep i'll up vote the answer. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

be a bit more diligent about checking the values

```
$("#negativecustomnicotinevgInput, #positivecustomnicotinevgInput").click(function(){
    let n = Number( $("#customnicotinepgInput").val());
    let id = $(this).attr("id");

    if ( isNaN( n)) n = 0;  // make sure it's a number

    if( id == "negativecustomnicotinevgInput"){
        $("#customnicotinepgInput").val(n+5);
    }
    else if( id == "positivecustomnicotinevgInput"){
        $("#customnicotinepgInput").val(n-5);

    }

});
```